# Cannot load vector in ghci due to shadowed dependencies

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghci

Whenever I try to load the vector package in `ghci` I get the following:

```
Prelude> :set -package vector
cannot satisfy -package vector:
    vector-0.12.0.1-6mmeV84KOvJADXavl6mOiY is unusable due to shadowed dependencies:
      primitive-0.6.2.0
    (use -v for more information)
```

`vector` is installed in my cabal sandbox and I'm running `cabal repl` to get to `ghci`. Is importing vector simply not possible or is there a way around it? I'm on OSX.

Comment: Can you include a minimal sequence of steps necessary to reproduce the observed behaviour (the first step being the one which immediately follows a clean installation of Haskell)?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what is causing that error message in your case, but one possibility is to use Stack's `ghci` command like so:

```
stack ghci --package vector
```

You can get Stack by following the instructions at https://haskell-lang.org/get-started, or since you're on OS X by running:

```
curl -sSL https://get.haskellstack.org/ | sh
```

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue with full 8.2.1 binary platform builds that's just been resolved: https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2017-October/127979.html

This was likely an instance of that.